# In Verilog, how to wait for level-sensitive and edge-sensitive events simultaneously?

Tags: verilog, wait, test-bench

When writing a testbench in Verilog, in a "task" I need to wait for such an event to occur, that is: while **signal_a** is *1'b1*, **signal_b** is having a *posedge*. However, unfortunately I tried but got no good solution:

```
@(tb_hready and posedge tb_hclk)        ;//(1)
wait(tb_hready) @(posedge tb_hclk)      ;//(2)
wait(tb_hready && posedge tb_hclk)      ;//(3)
if(tb_hready) @(posedge tb_hclk)        ;//(4)
```

(1) is grammar error;

(2) grammar is good, but it will first wait for **tb_hready** to go high, then pick up the posedge even if **tb_hready** is low again; -- this is not what I want.

(3) is grammar error;

(4) grammar is good, but does NOT implement what I want, seems like in such expression it does NOT "wait" for **tb_hready** to become high at all.

I figured this should be something rather easy, but I just cannot get what I want, nor does Google help much. Anyone have any suggestions? thx~~

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to wait for `signal_b` positive edge and when it occurs check if `signal_a` is active?

Comment: Then how would the code be like?

Comment: @(posedge signal_b) if (signal_a)

Comment: Got it, thank you buddy~~ @Prashant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@(posedge tb_hclk iff tb_hready)
```